# No puedo obtener los eventos de firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Estoy tratando de ejecutar una función de firebase al registrase un evento
para esto en android registro un evento como este

```
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "1");
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "nombre");
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

y en el index.js de las funciones tengo esto

```
exports.sendCouponOnPurchase = 
functions.analytics.event("select_content").onLog((event) => {
const user = event.user;
console.log('evento registrado ',user)
});
```

el evento no aparece en la tabla de evento de firebase pero si en la pantalla de debugview sin errores. tampoco activa la función de firebase
puse también el evento select_content" como evento de conversión.
Los eventos aparecieron el día siguiente en la pantalla de eventos y también activaron la función, tenia entendido que esto solo solo era para la pantalla de log de eventos

Comment: Firebase Analytics no es en tiempo real, se demora en actualizar la informacion aprox de 3 a 4 horas o algo aproximado a eso. Por otro lado, firebase comenta que esto puede durar hasta 24 horas como tu estas diciendo, por ello te pasa esto. Lo que podrias hacer es que uses la base de datos de firebase y registrar un nuevo registro cuando un usuario se registra y usar un onChildEvent() y cada vez que se registre nueva data se mostraria tu log. Saludos.

Comment: después de las 24 horas apareció en la pantalla de eventos y las funciones empezaron a funcionar correctamente, ahora se activa la función a pesar de que no aparece en la ventana de registro, igualmente tuve que cambiar las cosas por que la aplicación era para recibir noticias o eventos del dia y tendría que estar llamando a cada rato por si hay uno a ultima hora, ahora lo hago con la base de datos

Comment: Me fue bien, cambie el codigo para cuando entro al lugar se ponga a escuchar la base de datos y cuando salga deje de escucharla